# mappedby and JoinColumn issue during hibernate upgrade

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an old Ant based project that uses spring and hibernate (We manually add dependency jars to build path).

As part of a change, we had to upgrade hibernate version (from 3 to 4) (also added few new jars as well)
After this version upgrade, we are facing few issues that are caused due to the mappings.

In few of the entity classes, we have both these annotations for the same field:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="xxxx", cascade = PERSIST, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="xxx", referencedColumnName="xxxxx")
```

But after the version upgrade, we cannot have both mappedBy and JoinColumn together. In some cases we tried removing mappedBy and in some cases we tried removing JoinColumn. It works in some cases, but it doesn’t work across the app. Is there any way we can retain this mapping/relation in hibernate 4.

This is the main issue that is causing trouble on multiple functionalities.

Comment: This is just invalid mapping. See the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional): *Every bidirectional association must have one owning side only (the child side), the other one being referred to as the inverse (or the `mappedBy`) side.*

Comment: @SternK , what do you mean by invalid mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stated in the JPA specification (see section *2.9 Entity Relationships*):

> The following rules apply to bidirectional relationships:
>
> - *The inverse side of a bidirectional relationship must refer to its owning side by use of the `mappedBy` element of the `OneToOne`, `OneToMany`, or `ManyToMany` annotation. The `mappedBy` element designates the property or field in the entity that is the owner of the relationship.*
> - *The many side of one-to-many / many-to-one bidirectional relationships must be the owning side, hence the `mappedBy` element cannot be specified on the `ManyToOne` annotation.*
> - For one-to-one bidirectional relationships, the owning side corresponds to the side that contains the corresponding foreign key.
> - For many-to-many bidirectional relationships either side may be the owning side.

The `@JoinColumn` annotation can be used on the owning side of unidirectional or bidirectional `OneToOne` , `ManyToOne` associations OR with unidirectional `OneToMany`.

1. Bidirectional `@OneToMany`

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_PARENT")
class Parent {
   
   // We should not use @JoinColumn here, it should be used
   // on the the owning side of this association
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
   List<Child> children;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_CHILD")
class Child {

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "CH_PARENT_ID")
   Parent parent;
}
```

2. Unidirectional `OneToMany` (it was added in [JPA 2.0](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/What_is_new_in_JPA_2.0%3F)):

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_PARENT")
class Parent {
   
   // We should not use mappedBy element of the @OneToMany annotation here.
   // The name element of the @JoinColumn is referred to the
   // TBL_CHILD.CH_PARENT_ID column 
   @OneToMany 
   @JoinColumn(name = "CH_PARENT_ID")
   List<Child> children;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_CHILD")
class Child {

   // This part is absent as this is unidirectional OneToMany.
   // @ManyToOne
   // @JoinColumn(name = "CH_PARENT_ID")
   // Parent parent;
}
```